# Find Repeater Nested Anywhere Inside Another Repeater

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor

Using Protractor, I'm having issues locating a repeater which is nested inside another repeater but not as a direct child element.

Example:

```
<li ng-repeat="1 in hello">
  <div>
     <div ng-repeat"2 in hey">
  </div>
</li>
```

The technique I use for finding nested items assumes the element is a direct child as shown here https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/locators.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
element.all(by.repeater('outer')).get(0).all(by.repeater('inner'))...
```

will find all repeated elements inside first element of outer repeater. you can play with it using filtering to get elements you need.

Answer (score 0):

you can always make unique id for div element

```
<li ng-repeat="i in hello" id="{{i}}">
  <div>
     <div ng-repeat"j in hey" id="{{i}}:{{j}}">
  </div>
</li>
```

and find element by id